# Calling stored procedure from other stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

This is stored procedure #1:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp1]
AS
BEGIN       
    DECLARE @test varchar(255)
    exec @test = dbo.sp2
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        CMS_ORG.description, @test
    FROM
        CMS_ORG
END
```

This is stored procedure #2:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp2]
AS
BEGIN   
     SET NOCOUNT ON;
     SELECT 
         CMS_MAS.description  + '' + CONVERT(varchar(50),    
         CAST(CMS_ORG.amount AS money), 1)
     FROM 
         CMS_ORG
     INNER JOIN 
         CMS_MAS = CMS_ORG.GUID = CMS_MAS.GUID
END
```

The problem is here is I was not able to execute `@test` in stored procedure #1 by calling the stored procedure #2. When I execute sp1, I got a null values instead but when I execute the query of sp2 in sp1, I got a correct value. May I know what is the possible solution or similar examples which can solve the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your stored proc `sp2` *outputs* the result of a SELECT, but like all stored procs, it *returns* an integer using the `return` statement. You don't have a `return` statement, so Sql Server generates one for you: `return 0`. The purpose of the return code is to give feedback on whether it ran as expected. By convention, a return code of 0 means no errors.

This shows the difference between the return code and the output of a stored proc. Create a temp table `#output` to capture the rows of the `SELECT` that the stored proc outputs.

```
DECLARE @return_code int

-- capture the output of the stored proc sp2 in a temp table
create table #output( column_data varchar(max) )
insert #output( column_data )
exec @return_code = dbo.sp2   -- returns 0 because you have no RETURN statement

-- extract column_data from #output into variable @test
-- if there is more than one row in #output, it will take the last one
DECLARE @test varchar(255)
select @test = column_data from #output
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a table variable & Use it like this :

```
create proc test55
as
select 55  


declare @test table (Value Varchar(255))
insert into @test
exec   test55
Select * from  @test
```

Comment: do I create the table variable in sp1 ? and what create proc test55
as select 55  shows??

Comment: create table var in sp1 & select 55 is your query of sp2

Answer (score 0):

Your sp2 stored procedure will return table, not `varchar(255)`.

If you want to get a `varchar(255)` from sp2 you should be using function.

You can view in my example:

Define a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.function1()
RETURNS varchar(255)  
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER  
AS  
BEGIN  
     DECLARE @returnVal varchar(255);  

     SET @returnVal = (SELECT top 1 [ProductName]
                        FROM [dbo].[Products])

     RETURN(@returnVal);  
END;
```

And alter SP1 like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp1]
    @SMonth As Integer,
    @SYear As Integer
AS
BEGIN       
    DECLARE @test varchar(255)

    set @test = dbo.function1()

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT [ProductId], @test
      FROM [LearningKO].[dbo].[Products]
END
```